# How to create a dependency in Atmel Studio 7.0?

Tags: libraries, atmelstudio

I need to #include a file called ClearCore.h but it refuses to show up as a dependency.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kTvS.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn6XT.jpg

As you can see, the file is in the library and most other files are listed as dependencies, but this one refuses to despite being #included.

Here is the error message from compilation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM2wk.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I  am an applications engineer at Teknic and I saw your post and wanted to offer a few points to help you get your code running.

It sounds like you are having trouble adding the ClearCore library as a dependency.  As this is more a function of ATMEL, there could be several reasons as to why we are running into issues here.

The easiest way to troubleshoot this would be to use one of Teknic’s already linked and ready to run example projects (we include these examples in addition to the ClearCore libraries).  You can use the provided example projects as a template to sort out whatever may be causing the dependency issues.

You can find these examples here: https://teknic-inc.github.io/ClearCore-library/SdkExamples.html

Keep in mind that if you move the example projects into other directories, some of the relative file path definitions may be broken.

If you have any questions about the examples projects please feel free to give us a call at 585-784-7454, or use our "Contact Us" form online at https://www.teknic.com/contact/.

Best regards,
Mark D. – Teknic Servo Systems Engineer